# Problem with constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app, I have many constants, so I made a constants file named det_constants.yml for these constants.

```
/config/det_constants.yml

DEFAULTS: &DEFAULTS
    company_type:  { "Private"                     : 1,
                     "Public"                      : 2  }
development:
  <<: *DEFAULTS

test:
  <<: *DEFAULTS

production:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
```

I have a constants.rb file in lib folder, which loads this constant file.

```
/lib/constants.rb

module Constants
  # Allows accessing config variables from det_constants.yml like so:
  # Constants[:abc] => xyz
  def self.[](key)
    unless @config
      raw_config = File.read(Rails.root.to_s + "/config/det_constants.yml")
      @config = YAML.load(raw_config)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
    end
    @config[key]
  end

  def self.[]=(key, value)
    @config[key.to_sym] = value
  end
end
```

In my view file, when I do

```
<%= Constants[:company_type] %>
```

it throws an error

```
 NameError in Vendors#index 
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Constants
```

at line

```
<%= Constants[:company_type] %>
```

However, If i do the same thing in console, it runs properly,

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > Constants[:company_type]
 => {"Private"=>1, "Public"=>2}
```

I don't know where is the problem. if there is a new and better way to do this in Rails 3, please let me know.

```
Ruby version: ruby 1.9.2p110 (2010-12-20 revision 30269) [i686-linux]
Rails version: Rails 3.0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you need:

```
<% require 'constants' %>
```

Also, you will need to restart the server following changes in `lib/`; it doesn't catch them automatically even in development mode.

Comment: I just wanted to know if this is the best way to do this. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Well, it's not *bad* in any obvious way. I see that you like Ruby symbols; note that they can appear directly in yaml, **:thing: 123** as such. Also note that symbols may limit the need for the `enum` design pattern you are implementing. Consider the obvious alternative of `CONSTANTS::Const1`. I love the overloaded array operator for constants, but I'm not sure I would want to justify my use of it to the SW architect at my day job. :-)  I love "self.[]", now I have a new solution I must go try and think of a problem for it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about other solutions, I recommend you watch the railscast called [YAML Configuration File](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file). There are also some gems such as [Settingslogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) to help you with that.